# Trying to identify Renesas custom SoC through CPU die inspection

Tags: debugging, hardware, integrated-circuit

Was wondering if someone could help me identify which series a Renesas Custom SoC belongs to within the super-H family by looking at optical images of the die circuitry layout of the device, and by reviewing the other documents. [PDF of die analysis](http://www.mediafire.com/file/iu92vh0pmafd3k2/CPU_Inspection_X100642_M0KDP326_%281%29.pdf). (It's the part # R8A02021ABG) The device is mounted to a Roland GR-55 synthesizer, and what I'm trying to do is properly setup the unit's debugger so I can try to create simple patches for the firmware, like changing string names.

So far I've been able to identify that its a custom SoC by noticing that the unique part number which is written on the device is present in the die marking which is part of the metal layers. I was wondering if by looking someone could tell what functional blocks are on the die or the size of the memory/cache. I've identified it's in the super-H family by reviewing the [GR-55 schematics](https://www.joness.com/gr300/service/GR-55_SERVICE_NOTES.pdf)
 (PG.34) and seeing the port for the E10A-usb debugger/emulator. Also when reviewing the schematics for other Roland devices that use the same custom SoC like the Roland aerophone ae10, and Jupiter 80, I could see the debug port was labled E10A-usb. [E10a-usb supported devices](http://www.mediafire.com/file/5tmrn9xqsaualex/esupportdevice.pdf).

So with this info gathered i'm still unsure which series it belongs to. [Super-H series](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/products/microcontrollers-microprocessors/superh.html). I believe its most likely based off the SH-3-DSP or SH-4-DSP devices. I only say this because I know Roland is using DSP technology on the GR-55, and only devices in those series are using DSP. So from here I've been trying to see if there is a device in these series with a superset of features that are included in the GR-55 like DSP. I've also looked for A/D and D/A converters which the GR-55 states it has at 24 bit. (pg.3 GR-55 schematics) and none of the devices in this family have converters that go as high as 24 bit. when reviewing the schematics for the Roland Jupiter-80 I came across a note that looks like it states the clock speed of the custom SoC at 192MHz/64MHz but I don't know if it's stating the maximum clock speed or somthing els. I don't know how to interpret this note, and was wondering if someone could explain what it's saying. A similar note can be seen in the GR-55 schematics.  [image: Jupiter 80 schematics]

Also I was wondering if it's common for debuggers to provide any info on the devices they're connected to. Maybe the E10A-usb emulator can provide some info on my device.

[super-H devices specifications](https://datasheet.octopart.com/R5F100AEASP%23V0-Renesas-datasheet-12510943.pdf)

Comment: what is your final goal? This looks like an XY problem so far.

Comment: http://forum.pianoworld.com/ubbthreads.php/topics/2385759/roland-bk-9-internals.html - SH7700?

Comment: SH 7727 if you check the OS :)

Comment: I have also previously reviewed that post. I think the website is stating the OS supports the SH 7727 but does't specify if that is the processor in the BK-9. I think μITRON supports all the processors in the 7700 series.